# Need help in cross-domain form submit and processing result

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cross-domain

I have php page which contains form that submits values to another website. That website returns data that I need to resubmit, but result is plain text and I have no idea how to process that data to submit.

Here is what that website returns:

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">&lt;form action="XXXX" method="POST"&gt; 
 &lt;input type="hidden" name="MDORDER" value="489397f2-0425-4b05-86f3-7719d81c16c8"&gt; 
 &lt;br&gt; 
 &lt;input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok"&gt; 
 &lt;br&gt; 
&lt;/form&gt;</pre></body></html>
```

(copied from Chrome inspect element)

I tried ajax submit, tried to get form with iframe but both didn't work

I dont know how to convert this to actual form that i could post with jQuery. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What code are you using to retrieve data from the other website?

Comment: Using ajax cross-domain requires permission from the other domain by using CORS headers with correct responses. So make sure you have permission to use that other service.

Comment: I can't see any relevance for that fact that this is cross-domain. Please update your subject to the real problem. And expand on this real problem in your question: What are you trying to achieve with the returned string? How do you want to *process* it?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Sorry for irrelevant topic, because I have no idea what to call my problem. What I want to achieve is that I want to convert the response they give into actual form on my page, so i could actually submit that form.
@Adam on my php page I just have form that submits values to external website with method `GET` and that website returns the result i showed above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery to do it, you can grab the contents of the return, and replace the encoded characters with what they should be and append it back, something like this (I put everything inside of a div with the class test):

```
var reformatted = $('.test').text().replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>');
$('.test').empty();
$('.test').append(reformatted);
```

And then just use jQuery to submit it like:

```
$('.test form').submit();
```

Here's a sort of working example, no submit though: http://codepen.io/caleboleary/pen/RrwWRJ